# .Net Async Task restrict calls/second

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

So, i've just been asked to restrict the number of calls my .Net Async code make to 5/second for a particular API that we are calling.

Example of our async calls

```
var mylist = new List<Task<ApplicantDetails>>();

foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    mylist.Add(getCandidateResumeAsync(result));
}
await Task.WhenAll(mylist);
```

and the actual call to the API insode of `getCandidateResumeAsync`

```
var candiateAttachmentsResponse = await Client.GetAsync(model["candidate"]["links"]["self"] + "/attachments");
```

I need to execute the `getCandidateResumeAsync` function only 5 times/second.

Any thoughts on how I can go about this?

Comment: There are *many, many* ways of achieving this. Are you looking for something quick-and-dirty, or something reusable and tweakable? Is this the only place in the code you need to do this kind of throttling, or do all calls to this service operation (or perhaps this service, or any service) need to be throttled this way?

Comment: I make multiple calls to this API and all must be restricted to 5/second. Quick and dirty is acceptable as currently our product is offline until we get this implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a semaphore to track how many calls to the API are currently running, and then release one every time a call finishes.  Something like this:

```
public class Throttle
{
    private readonly TimeSpan perPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim actionSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(5, 5);

    public async Task Queue(Func<Task> action, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        await actionSemaphore.WaitAsync(cancel);
        try
        {
            await action();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.Delay(perPeriod, cancel).ContinueWith(_ => actionSemaphore.Release(1), cancel);
        }

    }
}
```

perPeriod would be set to 1 second, and actionSemaphore would be set to 5, meaning it will allow 5 requests to run at once.  You would call it like:

```
Throttle t = new Throttle();
t.Queue(SomeAction, CancellationToken.None);
```

You can then wait for all tasks to finish.

Comment: If `action` is potentially slow (or has lots of variability of timing), you may want to compute your "release time" before invoking it and compute a new TimeSpan afterwards by comparing the release time and current time.

Answer (score 0):

In such case you can use a limitation of parallel tasks instead of limiting the tasks per second.

```
  static async Task  Main(string[] args) {

      const ushort maxConcurrentTasks = 5;

      var resultBag = new ConcurrentBag<ApplicantDetails>();
      var queue = new ConcurrentQueue<JToken>(items);

      var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxConcurrentTasks)
        .Select(_ => GetResultAsync(queue, resultBag));

      await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

      var result = resultBag.ToArray();
    }

    private static async Task GetResultAsync(ConcurrentQueue<JToken> queue, ConcurrentBag<ApplicantDetails> resultBag) {
      while (queue.TryDequeue(out var queueItem)) {
        var result = await getCandidateResumeAsync(queueItem);
        resultBag.Add(result);
      }
    }
```

I know it's not exactly what you're looking for. But maybe this approach is also acceptable for you.

Comment: This is "max 5 at any time" rather than "max 5 per second". It may be that the former is what the OP actually needs but their stated requirement is the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions guys.

Just adding this in case it helps someone else in future.

Here's what I came up with and it seems to be working ok.

```
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (JToken result in results)
        {
            counter++;
            if ((counter % 5) == 0) Task.Delay(1000);
            mylist.Add(getCandidateResumeAsync(result));
        }
```

Comment: `Task.Delay` returns a task. If you're not doing anything with that task, calling it is *almost* meaningless (of course, the actual call overheads still effect you, and the machinery which arranges for the task to be completed at the appropriate time is still invoked). Which means you could take out this counter stuff and it'd be almost the same. This code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever In the end the API provider changed their mind and asked that I restrict the calls to 10 concurrent threads so this code is no longer in use. I'd be interested to see your suggested solution for the 5/second requirement for future reference.

Comment: I liked [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55643886/15498) for the requirement as stated, possible modified as per my comment.